# How to handle errors using Nominatim?

Tags: python, error-handling

I am running a Nominatim web service by geopy, but it fails very often, due to usage policy or maybe Internet connection. How can I handle failing connection with a stop, and rerun the code after several seconds or minutes. The error message is:

```
GeocoderServiceError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection 
failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

and

```
GeocoderServiceError: HTTP Error 420: unused
```

The pseudo codes would be like:

```
try:
    run web service
except:
    stop several seconds or minutes and rerun webservice at the same line and loops
(if it fails again)
    stop 30 minutes and rerun webservice
```

Any hint or suggestions will be the most welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should figure out, why does it fall so often. That should not happen.

Comment: Try not to use phrases like `I wonder` - Instead ask a question, like `How can I`

Comment: It's very superficial but just put this code in a `while` loop, Also try / except doesn't "ignore the errors" it's the exact opposite, You need to know which error you want to catch and what to do with it, the except tag will not work twice at the same try except it's not one after another but except1 or except2 or .... exceptN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the above comments. Revising try/ except is the solution.

Based on the geopy documentation (http://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#exceptions), the most common exception of using geopy is GeocoderServiceError. Here is the revising code to handle errors.

```
try:
    run web service
except geopy.exc.GeocoderServiceError as e:
    if e.message == 'HTTP Error 420: unused':
        time.sleep(1800)
        run web service
    elif e.message == '<urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>':
        time.sleep(5)
        run web service
```